# How do I convert an NDFrame to a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't seem to find any information around converting an NDFrame to a DataFrame. I am looking to do this as I can't seem to write an NDFrame to a CSV file. I've tried the code below, but it still returns an NDFrame. How do I make this conversion? Or how do I write an NDFrame to CSV?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Here is the error I'm receiving: 
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_compression_method' from 'pandas.io.common'

Comment: A dataframe is a subclas of NDframe object, what does your ndframe look like, what have you tried, and what was your result? If you're getting an error, please include the full error traceback

Comment: 3 and more dimensional objects can be hard to represent in a csv which is just a 2D.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why I'm even getting an NDFrame in the first place. I'm using SASPy and converting a SAS object to a pandas data frame.

Comment: I am receiving the same message only by trying to create a dataframe from a list of dictionaries. I actually am using Pandas 1.0.

Comment: by chance are any of you trying to write to csv using index=False? I removed index=False from the csv write back and this solved my issue.